# Using Count and Average in one Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table like that

[image: Exam_Result]

and i want to see average score(if student have 3 scores for each course, student can join many course) for each student for each course.
But I couldn't create the sql query.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for aggregation?

```
select student_id, course_id, avg(score * 1.0) as avg_score
from exam_result
group by student_id, course_id
having count(*) >= 3;
```